# i need help to pass mysql/php variable to javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

im trying to get the id of the picture the user selected to rate with the onclick,however it will only alert "null". when the user selected the div tag, it will alert the id. i want to display the id. i can build off of this and then implement ajax to rate the picture. But, i need help on getting the id of the picture the user selected.

```
 <?php

mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db("ajax");
$query="SELECT * FROM xxxx";
$result= mysql_query($query);

while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$rating=$row['ID'];
  echo "<img src='".$row['filepath']."'>";
  echo "<br>";
  echo "<div id='".$row['ID']."' value='".$row['ID']."' onclick='getrating();'>Likes: ".$row['Likes']."</div>";
  echo "<br>";

}

im trying to get what picture the user selected to rate.

?>
<script type="text/javascript" >


function getrating(){
var x= document.getElementById("<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>");


alert(x)



}
</script>
```

Comment: A `div` can have no `value` attribute. And the `id` should not start with a number, unless you use HTML5.

Answer (score 3):

A few things that you should do:

1. Try giving an id which starts with a letter for example, when writing the HTML code use:

   ```
   echo "<div id='img" . $row[ 'ID' ] . "'></div>"
   ```

   Note that i've added a prefix 'img' to the div's ID.
2. You have to pass the correct index to the javascript function because you are drawing the divs in a list but not the javascript function:

   ```
   onclick='getrating( " . $row[ 'ID' ] . " );'
   ```

   Now the javascript function will get the correct image ID when called upon clicking the respective DIV element.
3. Change the javascript function to:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" >

      function getrating( id )
      {
          var x = document.getElementById( "img" + id );
          alert( x );
      }

   </script>
   ```

Comment: function getrating( id )
so the parameter id just "id"?

Comment: @mayank23: yup, just ID, and while echo-ing the DIV from PHP, every time you do ...onclick='getrating( " . $row[ 'ID' ] . " );'... the value of the current ID will be sent to the javascript for example, for if the ID is 48, the resulting HTML will be: onclick='getrating( 48 );' which means that when the DIV will be clicked, the value 48 will be sent as the id value to getrating() and the element it will try to locate is: img48

Comment: so basically you took out value from the div? and wrote this?

Comment: "<div id='img" . $row[ 'ID' ] . "'onclick='getrating( " . $row[ 'ID' ] . " );'</div>"

Comment: @mayank23, well, i kept it on the DIV but you could get rid of the image all togather like you're suggesting if it doesn't serve any other purpose besides handling the click (the image can do that by itself).

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i still get null even with this as the code echo "<img src='".$row['filepath']."' value='".$row['ID']."' id='".$row['ID']."' onclick='getrating(this.value);'>";

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="getrating(this.value);"
```

That code will pass the current value attribute of the div to the function you made in JavaScript.  Be sure to add a parameter to your function to receive the data.

Comment: This is correct but sort of a sloppy answer... he'll need to change the function definition as well.

Answer (score 0):

Easy.

Change this:

```
  echo "<div id='".$row['ID']."' value='".$row['ID']."' onclick='getrating();'>Likes: ".$row['Likes']."</div>";
```

to this:

```
  echo "<div id='".$row['ID']."' value='".$row['ID']."' onclick='getrating(this.value);'>Likes: ".$row['Likes']."</div>";
```

And this:

```
function getrating(){
    var x= document.getElementById("<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>");
```

to this:

```
function getrating(row_id){
    var x= document.getElementById(row_id);
```

Comment: echo "<div id='".$row['ID']."' value='".$row['ID']."' onclick='getrating( this.value);'>Craves: ".$row['craves']."</div>";                                                                                                                                              function getrating(row_id){
                   var x = document.getElementById(row_id);
    
              alert(x);                                                                                                                                         i put this in, but it only displays null

Comment: Check your markup. What gets generated? Do divs have proper ids and values?

Comment: this gets generated by the browser:

Comment: <img src='images/2.png'><br><a id='12' value='12' onclick='getrating( this.value);'>likes: 0</a><br><img src='images/Cover.jpg'><br><a id='14' value='14' onclick='getrating( this.value);'>likes: 0</a><br>          <script type="text/javascript" >
               function getrating(row_id){
                   var x = document.getElementById(row_id);
    
alert(x);
}
    </script>

Comment: Why do you have `<a>` here and `<div>` in the question?

Comment: i had just changed the tag to a just to see if that would work. sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

You should put your event handler inside image like this:

```
<img src="" onclick="getrating(this.value)">
```

And you function should be like this:

```
function getrating(row_id){
    x = document.getElementById(row_id);
    alert(x);
}
```

Comment: echo "<div id='".$row['ID']."' value='".$row['ID']."' onclick='getrating( this.value);'>Craves: ".$row['craves']."</div>"; function getrating(row_id){ var x = document.getElementById(row_id); alert(x); i put this in, but it only displays null